# Rails: AJAX Script Won't Run

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a form that renders its errors via AJAX. The form is properly sending a remote request, and the server is returning javascript:

```
(function() {
  $("#main").fadeIn(". . .");
}).call(this);
```

Unfortunately, nothing actually renders in the browser. At first I thought there must be an error in the js code, but when I copy and paste this code into the Firebug console, it properly fades in the new content. The problem seems to be that the browser isn't running the code in the first place. What might cause this problem?

For reference, here's my form markup:

```
= simple_form_for @user, html: {multipart: true}, remote: true do |f|
  . . .
  .btn.btn--positive = f.submit
```

And here's the controller action:

```
def update
  if @user.update(user_params)
    redirect_to @user, notice: t('shared.notices.item_was_successfully_updated', item: @user.name)
  else
    render layout: 'transition.js.coffee', action: 'edit'
  end
end
```

The error occurs when the update doesn't validate and Rails runs the line `render layout: 'transition.js.coffee', action: 'edit'`.

Comment: do you use the the postet javascript in the transition.js.coffee?

Comment: Try renaming your file *transition.js.haml* (I guess you're using HAML),  but you might have to use js instead of coffee if you do so...

Comment: @DennyMueller I do. The js file reads: `$("#main").fadeIn <%= yield %>`

Comment: as far I know u cant use common js in a coffee script. Maybe try to remove the .coffee first and then run it again. And also you need to add a .erb to the field to run the `<%= yield %>`

Comment: I'm using the [coffee-views](https://github.com/yury/coffee-views) gem which should allow this functionality, but I went ahead and converted to a basic erb to be sure. Unfortunately, I get the same results. The AJAX doesn't render, but if I copy and paste the response code into the console, it fades in as expected.

Comment: I guess you are on 3.2?

Comment: @DennyMueller This is actually using the Rails 4 beta. Might I have encountered an actual bug?

Comment: after digging and digging, I cant find something about `render layout: *js.coffee`. try `render :js => 'transition.js.coffee', action: 'edit'`

Comment: Sorry, I should have explained that. The javascript is within a layout file, after a recommendation [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16328472/rails-render-a-view-not-a-partial-from-within-a-view). It works in most cases when I'm using a responder, but here (because I'm making a direct render call) it's causing some problems. Unfortunately, if I just change `layout: 'transition.js.coffee' to `js: `transition.js.coffee`, my response is the text `transition.js.coffee` rather than an execution of the layout file.

Comment: mhm I dont have more ideas. Maybe a last one Im wondering about shouldnt it be `render :layout => 'transition.js.coffee'`

Comment: Looks like that renders the same effect. Thanks for all your help though, Denny!